# Directory Listener in C#

Tags: c#

Is there any library for listening a directory? I mean I have a directory and I want to be informed of any changes in it.

For example: when some files are deleted or created in the directory, I want to be informed. I don't want to use a timer and check the directory manually to detect any changes.

Comment: I've edited your question as best I could, but I couldn't understand "and check directory happened something different etc" so I couldn't rephrase it in correct English.

Comment: @JonSkeet cheers for edit. "timer event checks directory if something happened like created or deleted a file on it" ;)

Comment: See whether this final edit reflects what you meant.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). See the documentation for a complete example.

Comment: The "Visual Basic 2010 Programmer's Reference" book says the following (page 863): __The FileSystemWatcher seems to have a few problems. Sometimes it is overwhelmed and misses changes that it should see and it seems to get confused under some circumstances and either stop raising events or raise duplicate events. The control will hopefully improve over time but for now, use it cautiously.__

Comment: @JohnyL: It can certainly be used badly, and *does* need to be used carefully, but that sounds like an overly-broad warning to me.

Comment: I wanted to use ShellObjectWatcher from Windows API Code Pack, but  - alas - it doesn't dispose object, process is just stuck in Process Explorer. So, I decided to learn SHChangeNotifyRegister myself (which Code Pack relies on). I used [this](https://dotnettoys.wordpress.com/2012/05/28/daily-problems-how-to-write-a-filewatcher-in-three-possible-ways-today/) article for information.